# -1 usage python

Tags: python

I understand using 0 and 1 for true and false evaluation, but can someone please explain the use of -1 to me in the following. s is a file name string.

```
if s.find(".py")==-1:
    return False
```

Comment: This is in the Python documentation. http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find

Comment: -1: This question truly shows no research effort. You should just read the documentation of that function: `help(str.find)` in your interpreter.

Comment: RTFM: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Comment: This is obviously a new user account.  Let's try not to punish him too much...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `s.find()` method returns the index of the given substring in `s`.  It is a number between `0` and `len(str) - 1` in case the substring was found.  In case it was not found, `-1` was chosen as return value because it does not collide with any valid return value for the case that it was found.

Note that this line would be better written as

```
if ".py" not in s:
    return False
```

or -- with a slightly different but probably intended meaning -- as

```
if not s.endswith(".py"):
    return False
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find):

> Return -1 on failure.

In other words, it returns -1 if the substring is not found in the string.

Examples:

```
>>> s = "Hello, world!"
>>> s.find("el")
1
```

Note that `1` is not to be interpreted as a Boolean (Python has `True` and `False` as Boolean values). The `1` is the starting index where the substring is found. As another example, the 'w' is at index seven in the string:

```
>>> s.find("w")
7
```

Finally, `foo` is not in the string, so trying to `find` it returns `-1`.

```
>>> s.find("foo")
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

> Help on built-in function find:
>
> find(...)
>       S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
>
> ```
> Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
> such that sub is contained within s[start:end].  Optional
> arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
>
> Return -1 on failure.
> ```

It can return 0 if the searched string is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: And you can get to this help by entering `help(s.find)` into your python interpreter (assuming `s` is a string that you've defined).

Answer (score 1):

In this case -1 is used to indicate "not found".  The alternative is to raise an exception if the given string is not found.  I'm not sure exactly why it was decided to return -1 instead of raise an exception.  It could be performance related (raising exceptions is a little slower) or for aesthetics (you need a `try` block instead of just checking the return value).

Comment: Because for raising an exception you take `s.index()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a **convention**.

From the python doc (http://docs.python.org/library/string.html)

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
    Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.
```